# How to replace a pattern using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

```
string1 = "2018-Feb-23-05-18-11"
```

I would like to replace a particular pattern in a string.
Output should be `2018-Feb-23-5-18-11`.

How can i do that by using `re.sub` ?

```
Example:
import re
output = re.sub(r'10', r'20', "hello number 10, Agosto 19")
#hello number 20, Agosto 19
```

Fetching the current_datetime from datetime module. i'm formatting the obtained datetime in a desired format.

```
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%Y-%b-%d-%I-%M-%S")
```

I thought, re.sub is the best way to do that.

```
ex1 : 
string1 = "2018-Feb-23-05-18-11"
output : 2018-Feb-23-5-18-11

ex2 : 
string1 = "2018-Feb-23-05-8-11"
output : 2018-Feb-23-5-08-11
```

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : I have tried re.sub

Comment: I dunno, why people have down voted this. Can you please clarify or upvote this ?

Comment: Maybe you could try a bit more seriously ? Obviously the snippet you added in your last edit doesn't match your requirements.

Comment: How about looking python regex module reference?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'((?:[^-]+-){3})0', r'\1', string1)`

Comment: `re.sub( r'(?<![,.\d])0*(?=\d)', '', '2018-Feb-23-005-18-011')` also remove leading 0 but the OP didn't explain what he wanted to do

Comment: @S.Jovan , Nahuel Fouilleul : Thanks. both methods are useful in different way. That's what i was looking for. How to add zeros (say, str(i).zfill(2)) . can we combine both remmoving zeros and adding zeros in a single re.sub expression ?

Comment: Use `re.compile` and `lambda` like `regex.sub(lambda x: 'do somthing', string1)`

Comment: It would be clearer if you gave some more examples along with expected outputs for each of them. At the moment, simply removing leading zeros as in your example could be done by `string1.replace('-0', '-')`

Comment: @MartinEvans Updated the question with examples.

Comment: So you want a leading zero for minutes only? What would `2018-Feb-1-0-0-0` give, i.e.midnight?

Comment: @MartinEvans yes, for minutes only. 2018-Feb-1-0-00-0 [like str(i).zfill(2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with dates and times, it is almost always best to convert the date first into a Python `datetime` object rather than trying to attempt to alter it using a regular expression. This can then be converted back into the required date format more easily.

With regards to leading zeros though, the [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) only give leading zero options, so to get more flexibility it is sometimes necessary to mix the formatting with standard Python formatting:

```
from datetime import datetime

for test in ['2018-Feb-23-05-18-11', '2018-Feb-23-05-8-11', '2018-Feb-1-0-0-0']:
    dt = datetime.strptime(test, '%Y-%b-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    print '{dt.year}-{}-{dt.day}-{dt.hour}-{dt.minute:02}-{dt.second}'.format(dt.strftime('%b'), dt=dt)
```

Giving you:

```
2018-Feb-23-5-18-11
2018-Feb-23-5-08-11
2018-Feb-1-0-00-0
```

This uses a `.format()` function to combine the parts. It allows objects to be passed and the formatting is then able to access the object's attributes directly. The only part that needs to be formatted using `strftime()` is the month.

---

This would give the same results:

```
import re

for test in ['2018-Feb-23-05-18-11', '2018-Feb-23-05-8-11', '2018-Feb-1-0-0-0']:
    print re.sub(r'(\d+-\w+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', lambda x: '{}-{}-{}-{:02}-{}'.format(x.group(1), int(x.group(2)), int(x.group(3)), int(x.group(4)), int(x.group(5))), test)
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Martin Evans.                                                                  Can it be achieved through regex too (as what we were discussing earlier) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)** module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

string1 = "2018-Feb-23-05-18-11"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(string1, "%Y-%b-%d-%H-%M-%S")
print("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}".format(d.year, d.strftime("%b"), d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-Feb-23-5-18-11
```